# How can pass Hudson/Jenkins parameters to windows batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, jenkins, hudson

well i need to execute a batch file in my Hudson Job, I have a parameter(Jenkis parameter) and i need to pass this value like param to batch file, i tried this:

```
Deploy.cmd -configuration=${DEPLOYCONFIGURATION} -source=${DeploySource}
```

My Deploy.cmd is configurated for get this values but Jenkis doesn't assign the values.. For example, i have this:

```
${DEPLOYCONFIGURATION} = DEV
${DeploySource} = c:\myFolder
```

Then,the batch file take this values

```
%DEPLOYCONFIGURATION% = ${DEPLOYCONFIGURATION} 
%DeploySource% = ${DeploySource}
```

Takes the parameter name not its value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Execute your Batch file as like the below

```
Deploy.cmd -configuration=%DEPLOYCONFIGURATION% -source=%DeploySource%
```

In case your Jenkins server run in unix/ Linux machine use "export" command to set environment variable for windows use "set" command like the below

For Windows:

```
set DEPLOYCONFIGURATION=DEV
set DeploySource=c:\myFolder
```

For Unix:

```
export DEPLOYCONFIGURATION = DEV
export DeploySource=c:\myFolder
```

Hope it might solve your issue.

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 23):

Use `%DEPLOYCONFIGURATION%`  instead of `${DEPLOYCONFIGURATION}`  in windows batch command

Comment: Is there a way to change the value of DEPLOYCONFIGURATION in windows batch command?