# give build number from jenkins to use in current matlab script and use it as an input variable in matlab

Tags: matlab, jenkins

I have problem in integrating matlab with jenkins. I want to use build number of jenkins job in my matlab script to generate file with name as build number and it has output variable of matlab script. I have tried it from last 10 hours, but no any related post I found.
I had look in jenkins plugin. there is also no any possible solution.
please help me out.

Comment: you are running matlab script through how? In `Execute Shell`?

Comment: i am using batch file to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass your build number to the batch script and you can simply access it from your script. You can access build number from your shell script by `$BUILD_NUMBER`. In order to view whole jenkins env vars, Please see this url `http(s)://<your jenkins url>/env-vars.html/`. So final script will be like,

```
sh <script name>.sh $BUILD_NUMBER
```

You can access the build number argument by `$1` in shell script. For more clarity reading arguments in shell script please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31417/282124).

Comment: should this shell script pass build number to my batch file? should i have to write this as an variable in my batch file? I think, it will just work for shell script not for batch file.

Comment: replace `$BUILD_NUMBER` with `%BUILD_NUMBER%`. For more info [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473652/how-can-pass-hudson-jenkins-parameters-to-windows-batch-command)